# how to sort the output of a map side program in mapreduce?

Tags: java, sorting, hadoop, mapreduce

My question is about how I can sort the output of a mapper in a mapreduce program(ps: there is no reducers(0)), i use just the map side to filter two inputs and I want that the result(output mappers) will be sorted per key of each mapper. How can I do this sort in the same job without using an additional job? Please your suggestions

Comment: By default, Hadoop framework sorts the mapper output by key. so in your mapper class map the field as key that you want to sort by.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in my case i want to use just a map job without reducer, because i have two inputs to process and each one with a mapper and i want that the result from each one will be sorted by key

Comment: Yes That is what I am suggesting. your job should have one mapper class. when you run the job, just provide input dir name in which you can have your two files that you want to map. if you have 100 files in that directory, job will process all 100 files. MR job input does not have to be one single file. one job can process many files inside provided input path.
`hadoop jar your.jar youMRclassName /input/dir/ /output/dir`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a partial (per Mapper) ordering by collecting all of the intended results into a local/in-memory data structure on the Mapper. You would then sort it and finally run the `collector.write` for all of the elements of the now-sorted collection.

So the distinction here from the vanilla behavior is that in the latter case each of the elements is simply emitted *as they are encountered* - resulting in a random / non-ordered output.

Note that the result will still not have `total ordering`: that will require a Reducer step.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i still don't understant how i can do this : collecting results into a local data structure and sort it before than i run the context.write? as i know if we have a reducer the framework do this automatically but in my case i want to sort directly the results for (two mappers) because i have just two mappers each one for a ninput (MutilpleInputs)

Answer (score 0):

Three files in one dir - sorted by one mapper in one job. Run as
`hadoop jar sort.jar sort file:///path/sortFiles/ sortedFiles`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;


public class sort{
    public static class sortMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {
        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            //add filter logic here
            context.write(new Text(value), new Text(""));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

          if(args.length != 2)
          {
              System.out.println("missing agrs: usage <prog> <arg1> <arg2>");
              System.exit(1);
          }
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "sort mutilple files");
        job.setJarByClass(sort.class);
        job.setMapperClass(sortMapper.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1])); 

        job.waitForCompletion(true);
      }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for your answer but the program i have is about filtering two inputs(for example: Transaction and Customer), the filtering(by Intersected Bloom Filter) is the role of each mapper, and i get the result filtered output (T',C') but this output is not sorted and i wand that by the end of the function of filtering i get the results filtered

Comment: the output of a mapper by default is not sorted if we don't have a reducer